# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden while using master page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I created a new project asp.net empty web application and added a master page, but when I executed the program it gives me the following error

```
                        HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
                  The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I have already tried to enable the directory browsing from internet information manager (IIS)
thanks

Comment: you have to add a web page that uses the masterpage, you can not surf to the masterpage itself. And because you have no valid pages to show it gives the error